# Items go over the rounded recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, listview, android-recyclerview

I created a recycler view and I added a rounded rectangle with 2dp stroke to it as a background, but when items go in and out of the frame the go over the rounded corner

I tried adding paddings and margins but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try using MaterialCardView for this issue, because it is very helpfull for this type of issue, like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardElevation="0dp" >

    //Place your recyclerview here with matchparent

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```